# What happens if ~3.3v is connected to a GPIO set as output?

Tags: gpio, output

If ~3.3v is connected to a GPIO set as output, would it damage anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly.

If the gpio is at logic 1 it is already at 3V3 so there will be no difference.

If the gpio is at logic 0 it is at ground and connecting 3V3 will in effect be a short-circuit.  That can kill the gpio and or bank of gpios and or the Pi (unless an appropriate current limiting resistor is in place).